# How do i get the status code for a response i subscribe to using the JDK's HttpClient?

Tags: java, java-11

Java 11 introduced a new standard [HTTP client](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/package-summary.html). A request is sent using [`HttpClient:send`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html#send(java.net.http.HttpRequest,java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandler)), which returns a [`HttpResponse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpResponse.html).

The [`HttpResponse::statusCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpResponse.html#statusCode()) method can be used to find the HTTP status of the response.

`HttpClient::send` also takes a [`BodyHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpResponse.BodyHandler.html) which is used to handle the body of the response. A useful family of `BodyHandler`s are those which wrap a [`Flow.Subscription`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Flow.Subscription.html), created with [`BodyHandlers::fromSubscriber`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.html#fromSubscriber(java.util.concurrent.Flow.Subscriber)) and relatives. These are a useful way of dealing with infinite streams of data, such as [server-sent events](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/server-sent-events.html).

However, it seems that if you use one of these `BodyHandler`s, the flow is delivered on the thread which called `HttpClient::send`, and so for an infinite stream, that method never returns. Since it never returns, you never get a `HttpResponse` with which you can determine the status.

So, how do i get the status code for a response i subscribe to?

Answer (score 3):

[As noted in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.html), these `BodyHandler`s

> do not examine the status code, meaning the body is always accepted

with a hint that

> a custom handler can be used to examine the status code and headers, and return a different body subscriber, of the same type, as appropriate

There does not seem to be a convenience method or class for this, but such a thing is moderately straightforward:

```
// a subscriber which expresses a complete lack of interest in the body
private static class Unsubscriber implements HttpResponse.BodySubscriber<Void> {
    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Void> getBody() {
        return CompletableFuture.completedStage(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Flow.Subscription subscription) {
        subscription.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(List<ByteBuffer> item) {}

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {}

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {}
}


// wraps another handler, and only uses it for an expected status
private static HttpResponse.BodyHandler<Void> expectingStatus(int expected, HttpResponse.BodyHandler<Void> handler) {
    return responseInfo -> responseInfo.statusCode() == expected ? handler.apply(responseInfo) : new Unsubscriber();
}

// used like this
Flow.Subscriber<String> subscriber = createSubscriberSomehow();
HttpResponse<Void> response = HttpClient.newHttpClient()
                                        .send(HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                                                         .uri(URI.create("http://example.org/api"))
                                                         .build(),
                                              expectingStatus(200, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.fromLineSubscriber(subscriber)));
```

Comment: If there is a cleaner way to do this, i would love to hear about it!